# Intellij 14 Glassfish Server is not connected. Deploy is not available

Tags: java, intellij-idea, glassfish

I'm trying to get my web app, which was developed and deployed successfully in Eclipse, to run on Intellij, but I failed. So I'm trying to get a basic app to run on Intellij with Glassfish first.

I'm following the steps in this tutorial https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Getting+Started+with+Java+EE+7+and+GlassFish+4.0. However, I can't deploy my app on to glassfish server. When I start the server from Intellij, this message appears:

```
C:\glassfish\bin\asadmin.bat start-domain domain1
[2015-06-25 10:45:58,857] Artifact Glassfish:war: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
Detected server admin port: 4848
Detected server http port: 9090
Waiting for DAS to start .........
Started domain: domain1
Domain location: C:\glassfish\glassfish\domains\domain1
Log file: C:\glassfish\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs\server.log
Admin port for the domain: 4848
Command start-domain executed successfully.
```

I'm using Java 6 with glassfish 3.0.1 (required by my company).
Glassfish server & deployed apps are running perfectly with eclipse.

I can't find any solution on the Internet. Please kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I did the following:

1. Run my IDE as an administrator in Windows.
2. Credentials I entered in the glassfish configuration for domain1 were incorrect.
            [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1Kx5.png)

I change the user and the password by user: admin and password: admin .Entering the directory:
       /glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/config

Open the file admin-keyfile and replace what I was for:

```
       admin;{SSHA256}t6QSpkyxWhpNFiV3RQ+LYgVczWIJVylE3f6akcXTRLJm9MKs983QAA==;asadmin
```

Open the file local-password and replace what I was for:

```
      6588CB5CBF61A96DB036AC047837A1C4468EC2C4
```

And ready new user and new password!and Enter the credentials in intellij.

I hope it helps you!